# NodeJS set cookie to domain issue?

Tags: node.js, setcookie

I am trying to set a cookie in the client domain using the nodejs and unfortunately, I am unable to save a cookie in my client domain. Am I doing this correctly??

```
const cookieOptions = {
            httpOnly: true,
            secure:false,
            maxAge:1000*60*60*24*5,
            domain:'.nhalearn.online',
            path: '/',
            sameSite: true
        }


res.cookie('authToken', token, cookieOptions).status(200).send(payload)
```

I am using express and cookie cookieParser

Answer (score 0):

[express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie) are pretty clear.
I had the same problem. You did correct, but somehow it is not working on local.
Now, mine is working on production.

I know it's not a good answer but hope to save someone's time.